# Optimizing GROUP_CONCAT query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, group-concat

I have a `messages` table with three fields

**Messages**

- idmessage
- text
- files

The `files` field can be `0` or `1`, it's set to `0` when the `message does not have files attached` and `1` when it `does`.

Then I have a `messages_files` table with three fields

**messages_files**

- id
- idmessage
- file

  id is just a primary `autoincremental` key, `idmessage` is the id of the message and `file` is the name of the file.

I want to list the messages and its files (if they have). The following query is working fine:

```
SELECT m.*, GROUP_CONCAT(mf.file SEPARATOR ',') AS fileList 
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN messages_files mf ON mf.idmessage = m.idmessage
GROUP BY m.idmessage;
```

My question is: since the *files* field in table *messages* is set to 0 when the message does not have files, can I "skip" the JOIN on those rows, thus making the query faster?

Thanks!

Edit: *message_files* has an index on the *idmessage* field (it's a foreign key).

Answer (score 1):

This might be faster using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mf.file SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM messages_files mf
        WHERE mf.idmessage = m.idmessage
       ) as fileList 
FROM messages m;
```

This can then take advantage of an index on `messages_files(idmessage, file)`.

Comment: Using *EXPLAIN* on this query returns a type ALL on the main query and no key is used.